# Deploying PHP WebAPI to Server

Tags: php, asp.net, node.js, api, asp.net-web-api

I have a solid understanding of html, css, and js, but I don't understand the whole WebAPI system and how it operates on a server. I do understand how to write a WebAPI using ASP.Net, but I don't understand how it actually operates and is deployed on a server.

Here's my situation... I'm trying to deploy a proof-of-concept of an Autodesk Forge web application on my personal website.(This app uploads to and accesses data on an Autodesk bucket) I'm using the following GitHub sample:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels (contains separate branches for Node.js, php, .Net, Go, and Java versions), and I have deployed it just fine (.Net version) in Visual Studio through localhost. Unfortunately, When I used FTP to upload it to my personal website, and the API portion of the app seemed to fail with a 500 Internal Server Error. I assumed this was because I was running a .Net API on a Linux-Hosted Site, so I tried it again by uploading the PHP version. The PHP version also gave me the same error, so I'm beginning to question my understanding of the whole WebAPI system. 
[*Error Response Image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGWEV.png) I started probing my site with the same Get request that previously failed using Postman... but this time I tried changing my site path... searching around my site's hierarchy for API access at the different controller paths, but I never found it.

Essentially, I understand that you can declare special api routes (such as api/forge/buckets) to segment api access, but I'm coming to the conclusion that WebAPIs don't operate like other basic file types on the server, and you can't just plop your API code on a server in php form, sent a get request to that path + your route and expect it to work properly. I've been searching for more info on this for hours, but I guess I'm not asking the right questions. Some insight would be greatly appreciated! Thank You!